# How do you convert a textual domain into an IPv6 in Java?

Tags: dns, ip-address, ipv6, java

How can I convert a textual domain ([DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)) like `www.abc.com` to its equivalent [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) address like `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329`?

I tried using [`Inet6Address`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) but I ended up with an [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) address.

Example:

```
Inet6Address.getByName("www.abc.com").getHostAddress();
```

Gave me something like:

```
129.42.38.1
```

So I'm not sure where the issue is in this.

Comment: Try using `getAllByName` and looping through to see if there is an IPv6 address for that name.  The JavaDocs for `getByName` don't seem to indicate how the returned `InetAddress` is chosen.

Comment: @StevenM.Wurster It's not working.   Inet6Address.getAllByName("www.abc.com"); is giving me something like this:  [www.abc.com/129.42.38.1]

Comment: Doesn't look like that website is ipv6 ready? http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php

try using "www.ipv6tf.org"

Comment: @IanGabes I know for sure that I can ping the machine through its IPv6 address and I can connect to the database on that machine using the IPv6 address as well. So I know that the IPv6 is there and usable, but can't figure it out dynamically through the Java API

Comment: Yes, but resolving with the domain might not get you the IPv6 address. Are you running an in house DNS service, or are you resolving remote domains?

Comment: @IanGabes in house DNS.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy Here is an easy way to test if that domain has an ipv6 address it resolves to, from command line:
`nslookup your.domain`
if you see only IPv4 addresses, then you aren't resolving IPv6 address, and you have to play with your dns system